# $S/I$ is a direct sum of cyclic $\mathbb{K}[Z]$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $S=\mathbb{K}[X,Y,Z]$ and $I=(X^2+Y^2-Y, XY-1)$. I have to show that $S/I$ is a direct sum of cyclic $\mathbb{K}[Z]$-modules.

I denote $R:=\mathbb{K}[Z]$.

Then $S/I=R[x,y]$ where $x$ is the class of $X$ mod $I$ and $y$ is the class of $Y$ mod $I$.

I know that $x^2+y^2-y=0$ and $xy=1$. From these relations I have that $R[x,y]=R+Rx+Ry+Ry^2$.

I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Then isn't $S/I$ a direct sum of four rank 1 free module generated by $1$, $x$, $y$ and $y^2$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I don't know how to prove that is a direct sum.

Comment: I have no idea what's the role of $Z$ in this story, but $K[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-Y,XY-1)$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension $4$. Then just tensor (over $K$) by everything you want.